# Run non-inline JS locally in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, content-security-policy

I'd like to stick all of my separate JS scripts as files in another folder when developing locally. The only way I've been able to do this is if I don't declare the `meta` statement. However, by not declaring it, I of course get a warning.

> Electron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy) This renderer process has either no Content Security
>       Policy set or a policy with "unsafe-eval" enabled. This exposes users of
>       this app to unnecessary security risks.

Is there a way to do it locally without either ignoring or violating CSP?

Answer (score 3):

Set the following meta tag in the renderers.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'nonce-xxx or sha256-yyy' " />
```

Kindly checkout my github repo [electron-renderer-CSP-sample](https://github.com/sudhakar3697/electron-renderer-CSP-sample), containing samples for both nonce & SHA methods for internal & external js files as well.

**OR**

You can make use of preload argument in webPreferences while creating the main BrowserWindow.
In the main.js,

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
```

In the preload.js

```
        const remote = require("electron").remote;
// electron APIs
        window.appQuit = function() {
          remote.app.exit(0);
        };
// node modules
       window.notify= function notify(msg) {
       return require('node-notifier').notify(msg);
       };
// DOM can be manipulated from here (Refer 
// https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/preload.js)
```

Comment: No, my question has nothing to do with using the `remote` module. My question is about running non-inline JS scripts (i.e. `<script src='js/whatever.js'></script>`) from the renderer process (i.e. `index.html`) locally without either ignoring (i.e. not including the `meta` statement) or violating CSP. Modify your answer, otherwise I'll have to vote it down eventually.

Comment: but `default-src` and the like, when set to `self`, doesn't work locally. it throws the following error: `Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

Comment: @BugWhisperer you can't have inline script tags. only load from files.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. How can I load scripts with `script` tags without either ignoring or violating CPS locally? I'll be back in a couple of hours.

Comment: But `default-src 'self'` and `<script src='whatever.js'></script>` throws errors when you try to call functions in `whatever.js` from `index.html` (i.e. `<button onclick=someFunctionInWhateverJS()>`)??

Comment: @BugWhisperer Hi, check my github repo https://github.com/sudhakar3697/electron-renderer-CSP-sample [Working with nonce, will put a sample with sha-256]

Comment: @BugWhisperer https://github.com/sudhakar3697/electron-renderer-CSP-sample has now both the samples.

Comment: I'll check it out!

Comment: Interesting. So you used [Report URI](report-uri.com/home/hash) to generate the hashes? What value are you hashing? I tried generating a value for a new script and I'm getting this error: `Failed to find a valid integrity value`, but then the console spits out a hash, and if I use this one it starts working?

Comment: Just tried hashing the code in the actual document. Still the same issue: `Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/test.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'DwORLt76AXMp0OCxIrmViu/HIEZ3iKsAE1YY/oKr+5E='. The resource has been blocked.` It's weird because if I switch the hash to the hash the console just spit out (`DwORLt76AXMp0OCxIrmViu/HIEZ3iKsAE1YY/oKr+5E=`), then it will start working, which kind of defeats the purpose/security of it?

Comment: @BugWhisperer, I also noticed it. console just shows the actual hash of the code

Comment: Yes, utterly bizarre. So there's really no secure way to do it?

Comment: It seems like CSP is mostly stored in servers in web environment. [https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/02/implementing-content-security-policy/]

Comment: yes, for cross-origin, so maybe i shouldnt worry about it rn. its just annoying having fluff warnings and errors in the console